# Asynchronous thread in Android

Tags: android

I want to invoke a web service request every 1 minute. I'm not able to understand what should I use.

Comment: may be this could help you,do let me know its work or not thanks http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the service even when the screen is off for a while look  at AlarmManager to wake up the phone every 10 minutes plus a service with a wavelock to keep the service running. Bear in mind that the wavelock can drain battery.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) with a sleep and a loop in it.